# How to add the basic authentication to the HTTP triggered Azure Logic App

Tags: json, azure, authentication, azure-logic-apps

I have created an Azure Logic App with Http Trigger and then added the Service Bus – Send Message action.

Next, I’m calling the above logic app from third party system. There are no issues for calling the Http triggered logic app from third party system. But I want to add the Basic authentication to the Http triggered logic app.

Because whenever I’m calling the above logic app from third party system, I need to pass the Basic authentication details for security reason.

Answer (score 1):

in HTTP trigger select the last section(add new parameter) there you can find authentication option and in the drop down can select basic auth type

Comment: The question was about Logic App's HTTP trigger, not HTTP action.

Answer (score 1):

You could secure your Logic App using basic authentication by exposing it via [Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app?tabs=azure-portal#azure-api-management).

Without Azure API Management, you have the following options:

- [Shared Access Signatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app?tabs=azure-portal#sas) (SAS) - default option, which as I understand is not sufficient for your needs.
- You can enhance the security by allowing requests only [from specific IP addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app?tabs=azure-portal#restrict-inbound-ip-addresses).
- Logic Apps can be set up to use [Azure Active Directory Open Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app?tabs=azure-portal#enable-oauth) (Azure AD OAuth) instead of SAS.